Can't get if statement to work in LTSpice
I've looked nearly everywhere and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using LTSpice on Mac if that helps.



I can't figure out what you are doing, let alone figure out what you are doing wrong. Perhaps if you'd write more? Here's an IF example that works fine for me.

Figured it out! Need to change the prefix of voltage sources to "B"

@quote Please post your answer as an answer so  this question can be closed.

Does this mean you used the voltage symbol and changed the reference designators to match someone else’s schematic? If so, then the approach is wrong since you should be using the bv symbol for behavioral voltage sources. The prefix for that symbol is already set correctly.

Figured it out! Need to change the prefix of voltage sources to "B"

You shouldn’t have to if you use the bv symbol.  The voltage symbol is not meant for behavioral sources.
